# Splash not rendering page completely

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I have been learning using scrapy + splash for scraping web pages with js. I have a problem with one site - https://aukro.cz/mobilni-telefony - it is not rendering completely. Instead I have the whole page with empty list of products.

[scraped page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddvnh.png)

I have already tried modifying wait time and scrolling page with no effect. Lua script below

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash:go(args.url)
  assert(splash:wait(20))
  local scroll_to = splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
  scroll_to(0, 300)
  return {png=splash:png()}
end
```

What else should I do? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I have also disabled Private mode using : `docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode` with no help